# Thumbnail not enlarging on hover

Tags: css, image

I am not a CSS expert (but learning!) A client of mine asked me why his thumbnail images aren't bigger on hovering as they used to be. I don't know how big they used to be - maybe 600 pixels. You can see the issue on this eBay listing of his: http://www.ebay.com/itm/371767762931.

Comment: you need to share the code - or snippet and what you tried - on one in the community can help without looking at the code or snippet..

Comment: Can you show us a snippet of your code

Answer (score 0):

try this in your css

```
.tem_img 
{
    max-width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
img 
{
    max-width: 100%;//change this to 600%; and see what happens
    height: auto;
}
```

i just inspect the element and did that and it works 
[image: befor]
[image: After]